# EU tourist visa, study online for UK course?

Tags: visa

Is it possible to get a EU tourist visa to stay in France for a year (partner (not married) will be working on a long-stay visa) and complete an online master's programme at a university in the UK?

Do you only need a student visa if you are attending a university in France?

Comment: Have you looked at your visa eligibility via https://mail/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa?

Comment: There is no such thing as a EU tourist visa.

Comment: Yes I have done this (https://france-visas.gouv.fr/fr_FR/web/france-visas/ai-je-besoin-d-un-visa) but it is not clear what you are allowed to do with the visa. You can enter the country, but can you then study online on a UK course?

Comment: If you click "study" then it assumes you are travelling to study, if you click "visitor" you have to promise not to do any "professional activity". Does a online masters count as professional study?